# Weak-linking MediaAccessibility framework in Xcode 4 fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The MediaAccessibility framework was added to SDK7 and I would like to use it. However, our test-build system still uses xcode 4, and I still need it to work.

To support this on both iOS6 and iOS7, I weak-link the framework like this in my gyp file:

```
  'xcode_settings': {
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS': ['-weak_framework MediaAccessibility'],
  },
```

It works fine when building in xcode 5. I can build for iOS7 target and iOS6 target without issue. For the iOS7 target, the methods are available as one would expect, and for the iOS6 target, the methods aren't available since the framework is weak-linked. All good.

But in xcode 4, it fails to build with:

ld: framework not found MediaAccessibility

Is there any way for me to get xcode 4 to do the equivalent of "weak linking" for this framework that doesn't exist in SDK6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weak linking to a framework requires that the framework exist in the SDK you are using to build.

You may be able to use an SDK-specific setting for Other Linker Flags. That would add -weak_framework when the SDK is iOS 7 or later, and not add it when the SDK is iOS 6. The xcodeproj might look like this:

```
"OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=*]" = (
    "-weak_framework",
    MediaAccessibility,
);
"OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator6.1]" = "";
"OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos6.1]" = "";
```

Comment: That might work, but we are using GYP. I wasn't able to figure out a way, so we ended up just migrating everything to the iOS7 SDK a bit earlier than planned.